# Preventing direct file access

Tags: .htaccess, security, zip, file-access

I asked this question a while ago but did not receive an answer. I hope it is OK to post it again.

I store user uploaded ZIP files on my server. Nobody should be able to access these files except through site links.

For example: https://www.example.com/uploads/1.zip

If I provide a link to that file, the server should allow it, but if someone tries to access it directly by typing it in their browser address bar it should fail.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I've tried this (in htaccess). It prevents direct access, but also breaks the link:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(zip)$ - [F]
```

I also considered session tokens in the URL, but my understanding is that someone with a valid session will still have direct access.

These files will always be in their own "uploads" directory, if that helps.

From reading other questions here on SO it seems that this may be impossible. If so, is there a different solution for keeping files out of the hands of people who guess the file names?

Comment: It looks like you want a direct link to work...but only if you send it to them, correct? There's no reliable way to determine if the user typed in/guessed a link rather than clicking it or copy-pasting it (especially if you're sending the link in an email or something). Do you have any way to authenticate the users who should have access?

Comment: I agree with @retupmoca. Authenticating users seems to be the only reliable way. Another way would be to put long and random names to the files, so that it is extremely hard to guess. Since you are storing zip files it will not impact the end user a lot probably, as when unzipped the file names will look fine. This is, however, only if you only want to protect from guessing the file names. People to whom you have given the URLs will be able to email them around and others will be able to access them.